# socket.io return "connection error: xhr poll" error

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

i wrote simple web socket code by socket.io and the code run with no error and i can access it via browser with address localhost:5000. but when i test the connection with Socket.IO Test Client chrome extension or any other websocket  tester it return error **"connection error: xhr poll"**

my code

```
const objExpress = require('express');
const objApp = objExpress();
const objHTTP = require('http');
const objServer = objHTTP.createServer(objApp);
const {Server} = require('socket.io');
const objIO = new Server(objServer);


objServer.listen(5000,"localhost", () => {
    console.log("listening to port 5000");
});
```

do i miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a socket.io server and this is how it worked for me:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: thanks @Evripidis; can you tell my code problem cause i cant connect to it and how to pass HTML page as client to it